# Kentico - JSON serializing custom page type returns different data

Tags: json, serialization, json.net, kentico

We have a custom page type `Product` which, when serialized to JSON (using Newtonsoft) outputs different fields to the properties on the `Product`.

```
Product product = ProductProvider.GetProducts().FirstObject;
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
```

produces the following JSON:

```
{
  "LogSynchronization": 3,
  "ObjectType": "cms.document.apollo.product",
  "UpdateTimeStamp": true,
  "LastUpdated": "2016-09-26T16:23:58.9228865Z",
  "Locked": false,
  "DataClass": null,
  "UpdateVersionGUID": true,
  "Components": [
    {
      "LogSynchronization": 3,
      "ObjectType": "cms.node",
      "UpdateTimeStamp": true,
      "LastUpdated": "2016-09-26T16:23:58.9238891Z",
      "Locked": false,
      "DataClass": {
        "Locked": false,
        "IDWasChanged": false,
        "Data": [
          285,
          ...
          false
        ],
        "OriginalData": null,
        "ClassName": "CMS.Tree"
      },
      "UpdateVersionGUID": true
    },
    { ... }
  ]
}
```

Auto-generated `Product.cs`:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//
//     This code was generated by code generator tool.
//
//     To customize the code use your own partial class. For more info about how to use and customize
//     the generated code see the documentation at http://docs.kentico.com.
//
// </auto-generated>
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// ...

public partial class Product : SKUTreeNode
{
    #region "Constants and variables"

    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the data class.
    /// </summary>
    public const string CLASS_NAME = "MyProject.Product";


    /// <summary>
    /// The instance of the class that provides extended API for working with Product fields.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly ProductFields mFields;

    #endregion


    #region "Properties"

    /// <summary>
    /// ProductID.
    /// </summary>
    [DatabaseIDField]
    public int ProductID
    {
        get
        {
            return ValidationHelper.GetInteger(GetValue("ProductID"), 0);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue("ProductID", value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// My Custom Property.
    /// </summary>
    [DatabaseField]
    public string MyCustomProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return ValidationHelper.GetString(GetValue("MyCustomProperty"), 0);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue("MyCustomProperty", value);
        }
    }

    // Truncated. Lots more properties here...

    #endregion


    #region "Constructors"

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Product" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    public Product() : base(CLASS_NAME)
    {
        mFields = new ProductFields(this);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

How can I make this return an actual/traditional serialization of the `Product` class?

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting results because the `ProductProvider.GetProducts()` returning Base object **without any custom properties**. The Newtonsoft works with public properties of a class. You can generate your own class which you can then use to serialize by following [this documentation](http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/code-generators)

The best practice here would be to create your own model so that you don't necessarily pollute JSON with all the properties, but instead use only the ones you want and need.

Comment: In fact, the returned type is `Product` (the generated class) and I can access the custom properties in the code fine, just when serialized these do not show. I have updated my question to reflect this.
Unfortunately, pretty much all properties are required so a new model would be a bit of a maintenance pain.

Answer (score 2):

There is an extension method called **ToJSON** in CMS.DataEngine namespace. If you need to serialize the object the same way as Kentico REST, use that method.

If you need to only select some parts of the object and/or make some transformations to the data, the easiest way is to create a new anonymous object and initialize its properties manually.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're trying to get json object from UI I'd recommend getting it with REST service, which will do everything you need. See how you can use it [here](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Getting+data+using+REST).

Comment: We're actually doing a lot with the data retrieved before returning it as JSON. The `Product` is a small part of the returned object.

Comment: In this case answer from Enn is the way to go. Also I'd like to mention that you can implement Web API controller, so it will serialize object to JSON automatically and it is nice (if not the best) to consume it on a client.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide some more detail ideally. What type does `ProductProvider.GetProducts().FirstObject` return? A `TreeNode`? And what data are you expecting from the serialization?

I suspect your answer lies with [strongly-typed page type models in Kentico](http://johnnycode.com/2013/07/15/using-strongly-typed-custom-document-type-classes/). Using this approach you can take full control over how your page models are serialized because you can make `DocumentHelper` or `TreeNodeProvider` return a strongly-typed model which you can decorate with Netonsoft's serialization attributes e.g. `DocumentHelper.GetDocuments<MyCustomProductModel>().First()`

Comment: Be awar of using LINQ in Kentico queries. Calling First will actually load all objects in memory a then return first result from it. It will not limit the number of rows returned from db.